# Exporting mapping tables from GeoPackage to Excel

Tags: geopackage, domains, subtype

I have a couple of geopackges with attribute field that are configured using "value mapping". Is there a way to export those mapped values to Excel or CSV or something similar?

Comment: How did you configure the attribute field with value mapping ?

Comment: I didn't configure a thing, I received  some geopeckage with fields that are configured usiing forms, and I came to find out they used value mapping in the form. I have to dexcribe the model and found out that I van copy paste the values, but I wondered: is there a more easy way.

Comment: Witch software are you using ? where does the form come from ? how do you access the gpkg and what's in there ?

Comment: I'm using FME to transform the data into a filegeodatabase. 

The data I receive is an inventory data for a forest. In the filegeopackage, trees are digitalised by point, the form, is used to limit the possiblities of values you can use to complete your attribute table. It depoends on the type of tree which values you can use, hence the form. IN QGIS, you can acces the list of coded values by clicking on the layer properties, in the "forms" you can managethe "value maps" for certain fields. Copy/paste for these values works, but as there a lot of attributes,: is there another way?